# How do we customize the colors of navigation bar, basically the theme of foundation framework?

Tags: html, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I have downloaded the foundation framework from http://foundation.zurb.com/ with the default theme. 
I dont know how to change the colors of various things like navigation bar, buttons, add background and box with shadow for the body ! etc.

I tried to add the following to the app.css but it did not work

> ```
> body {
>   background-color: #333;
>   position: relative;
>   font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
>   color: #666666;     
>   border-right: 1px solid #333;
>   border-left: 1px solid #333;    
>   -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #888;  
>   -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px#888;    
>   box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #888; 
> }
> ```

Please suggest what to do.
There is something about scss+foundation but i am not sure what it is... scared to try it also , looks kinda scary. 
Din think using Foundation Framework was going to be this and complicated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy but needs a bit of work ... app.css does the trick by over riding the values inside foundation.css !!

But finding out which element or selector should be overridden is a not easy and especially without knowing most of css. But there is a way around this... i.e. firebug for firefox !
Its a wonderful application that tells me which style is being used anywhere in the website.

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is utilize tools such as Firebug (For Firefox) to inspect the element that you are interested in.  This will clearly let you see what CSS is actually in effect for the element and what file/line that code is in so that you can change it.  You can also override new values into the code right there in Firefox to see what effect it would have on your page.

Comment: If i have two css files and say i have two different properties for body on both of them. Which one will be used ?? will the order in which they have been declared make a difference?

Comment: @hunterr986 Yes, the order of stylesheet inclusion does make a difference, those CSS rules in a file included after another will override the properties declared in the first stylesheet.